# What is the word for the state of ignoring something?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, connotation

What is the word for the state of ignoring something?

For instance, if I am ignoring you, am I in a state of `ignorance`? Is there a better word with a less negative connotation?

Comment: The "negative connotation" directly derives from the normally intended meaning (I deliberately and consciously *do not wish* to be aware of you). If you don't want that (I'm in a state of ignorance regarding you, but not by deliberate choice) then you're just *unaware*. That's to say, you're in a state of [unawareness](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/unawareness)

Comment: The phrase *willful ignorance* is legal terminology to mean intentional avoidance of knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for **[ignoration](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ignoration)**.

> **1.** The state of being ignorant
>
> **2.** The action of ignoring something, or the state of being ignored

Answer (score 2):

Since you didn't mention that it necessarily needs to start with `ignore-` prefix, I think the most appropriate word for it is disregard.

Answer (score 0):

**Oblivion** ( Source: [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/oblivion) )

> the state of being unconscious or lacking awareness of what is happening around you
>
> the state of being completely forgotten by the public

*State of oblivion*
*The person is oblivious about your presence*.
*The person is in a state of oblivion*.
*You are oblivious to the person*

Answer (score 0):

This is the only way I had come to understand it ... in German. I'm aware that there's a huge difference, but I don't ya'll to remain *ignorant* of the fact.

Latin *-ans* derives present **active** participles.

Therefore, Latin derived English *-ant* is a doublette of itself: "partly (in adjectival derivations) continuing Middle English -ant, a variant of -and, -end, from Old English -ende (present participle ending), see -and." (https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ant), of which *friends* and *friends* are given as example, cp *I'm friends with them*!

I'm not sure what to make of that, you're example sentence is vexing because *in a state of* implies passivity. I mean, you are friends, a friend, or in a state of friendship.

However, wiktionary derives *ignorance* from *ignorantia*, cp e.g. *dementia* or *currency* for the suffix. The complete omission of the suffix might be due to errosion from different pronnounciations early on. *ignorancy* does not exist, sadly.

Beware though, the situations where such an explanation makes for a good come back are rather limited.

I'd say the negative connotation of the word stems in part from the denotrd state being simply negative. There's no way around that.